# c programming variable read/write restriction

Tags: c

In file1 I have defined a variable `int a = 5` and this can be modified in the file, I want to access the value of the variable a in file2, but I should not be able to modify the value here ex `a = 10` should not work.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have a way to make a variable only writable from certain places, but `static` is limited to that source file. So instead what you might do is have a "getter" function only, to keep the variable "hidden" in just the desired file.

```
// Header
int get_a();


// Source file1
static int a;
int get_a()
{
    return a;
}

void foo()
{
    a = 42; //OK
}

// Source file2
void bar()
{
    int x = get_a(); // OK, function in header
    a = x + 1; // Error, a was never declared in the header
}
```